# Why is CORS giving inconsistent results when 2 APIS from a same Python Flask api app is called from same Origin javascript

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, flask-cors

I have a python flask api app shown as below.

```python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

# creating a Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,origins = ['*'],send_wildcard = True)

@app.route('/getapi', methods = ['GET'])
def api1 ():

    return ({"text": "Hello World"})

    
@app.route('/putapi', methods = ['PUT'])
def api2():
    formtext = request.form.get("inputtext")
    return ({"text": formtext})

# driver function
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug = True)
```

I have a Javascript in an HTML page as below

```js
async function getText() {
  const api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getapi";
  const api_req = new Request(api_url);
  api_req.method = "GET";

  const response = await fetch(api_req);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}

async function putText() {
  const api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/putapi";

  const api_req = new Request(api_url);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  };

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("inputtext", "new text from browser");
  api_req.formData = formData;

  const response = await fetch(api_req, requestOptions);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

The webpage is run using a live server extension in VSCode and runs as http://127.0.0.1:5500/. Flask API is run as http://127.0.0.1:5000.

When I call the getapi, there is no CORS error. But when the script calls putapi, there is a CORS error in console

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/putapi' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Why this inconsistent behaviour? I also did try changing the method to GET instead of PUT. Still same error. From HTML, the getapi is called first on body onload. On a button click, the putapi is called.

Comment: There is no inconsistency. CORS intentionally allows "safe" HTTP requests that should not normally cause any server-side state mutation, so `GET` and `HEAD` are allowed (as those are normally strictly read-only operations) but `PUT`, `POST`, and `PATCH` have a much greater harm-potential, hence why CORS blocks them.

Comment: @Dai Thanks. I did change it to GET once, it still erred. What's the right thing to do here to do a PUT?

Comment: @Dai that's not entirely true. If you're talking about simple vs preflighted requests, `POST` is still considered _simple_ as long as the `content-type` is `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` and the other headers are within the [safe list](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header)

Comment: @Phil You are correct - I note that the `POST` requests that CORS allows are the exact same (and only) kind of requests you can make with a HTML `<form>` (without any JS) - so I assume it's allowed for the sake of not-breaking-the-web.

Comment: @Dai that is exactly it 

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending any request body. Your `PUT` request is malformed which is probably causing Flask to respond with an error, bypassing CORS configuration.

To correctly send a `PUT` request with `multipart/form-data` payload, use the following...

```js
async function putText() {
  const api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/putapi";

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("inputtext", "new text from browser");

  const response = await fetch(api_url, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: formData,
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Setting the request `body` to your `FormData` instance automatically sets the appropriate content-type header when sent from a browser.

---

Since you're not sending any binary data, you don't really need `FormData`. You could instead use `URLSearchParams` to send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body

```js
const response = await fetch(api_url, {
  method: "PUT",
  body: new URLSearchParams({ inputtext: "new text from browser" }),
});
```

or even just format the payload yourself but then you'd also need to supply the content-type header

```js
const response = await fetch(api_url, {
  method: "PUT",
  body: `inputtext=${encodeURIComponent("new text from browser")}`,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first suggestion - removed the content-type and set the body to formData - and it worked!!

Comment: Seems odd that `flask_cors` doesn't wrap around error responses. Perhaps it can be configured that way though